# How to mute an Android application when it goes into the background

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I've been trying to develop an application that has some background music in android studio, when I minimized the application/closed the application/put the application in the background the music oddly kept playing. It's my intention that the application doesn't make any sound when it is not visible.

Is there some way to completely mute an application when it goes into the background? All sounds are currently done using SoundPool.

So far I haven't tried much as I couldn't find usable information on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  lifecycle method to pause resume background song

```
@Override 
  protected void onPause() { 
     super.onPause();
     // pause your soundpool here 
  }
```

then on onResume

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      //resume that background song again
  }
```

Comment: Just to avoid possible confusion, I'll point out that the language doesn't really matter here. The solution will be the same in Java or Kotlin, just with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`SoundPool` has [pause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#autoPause()) and [resume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#autoResume()) functions. You can call these functions as appropriate in response to activity lifecycle events.

That said, `SoundPool` may not be the optimal choice for music. As far as I'm aware at least, it decodes the sounds you load into raw audio data, which can be sizable for a music track. Depending on what you're doing exactly, [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) or [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) might be a better choice.